# give an example of NSInMemoryStoreType , tell me scenario when it is required?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

when one should use NSInMemoryStoreType?because it stores only in memory then how it will be useful for persistence?

Comment: It can be very useful when writing unit tests against CoreData code. Advantages over using a file-based store type include: speed (which becomes particularly important as a project’s test suite grows), and clean-slate of the data for every test (which you can also do by manually resetting a file store, but that further slows down the test suite and can interfere with the development build of your apps if not handled correctly).

Answer (score 4):

Since it persists data in-memory, when you close the app, the data is lost for sure, and they can't be recovered.

But there is an advantage in using NSInMemoryType, and that is, speed. If you're going to save **100,000 data** using NSInMemoryType, it's going to take **45 seconds** to add them and getting the counts back using CountResultType.

Doing so using NSSQLiteStoreType actually takes **more than 3-4 mins** and thus it doesn't seem to be the best way to store all that data; unless post-application-relaunch persistence is a must.

A good use-case for In Memory would be an application which it's data changes every time the app launches or closes and there is **more than 1,000 records** to store. In that case, it's wise to persist the records in memory, since it's blazingly fast compared to NSSQLiteStoreType.

On the other hand, if the number of records to store is not much, there won't be any speed difference between SQLite and InMemory, and storing records using NSSQLiteMemoryType would be a much better choice.

I've compared the two and here's the results:

[image: Comparison results]

Answer (score 0):

The in memory store type does not "persist" because it is not writing to a file.

I had a good use case recently: an app reads a complex XML file and translates it into a Core Data object graph. The code is very readable and can take advantage of useful objects such as `NSFetchedResultsController`.

The only real possible argument for using the Core Data SQLite store was for allowing faster startup (not necessary to read the XML file), but that was not a project requirement.

The argument for the in-memory store is that it is much faster than a database backed persisted store.

Answer (score 0):

It's very useful if you already have a CoreData database with lots of code working with it, you want to extract some small amount of data, and use all your existing code with it, which means you need another CoreData database. Instead of having to create a new database in the file system with all the overhead involved, you can just create it in memory.